# Fetching data in core data

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data

I have Three tables, One to many relationship between Session and Album , One to many relationship between Album to songs , When I tried to fetch data from songs Then I get nothing

Here is my readFRomDB func

-(void)readDataFromDB{

```
AppDelegate *delegates = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = [delegates managedObjectContext];

if (runningSessionArray.count > 0) {
    [runningSessionArray removeAllObjects];
}

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSArray *searchResults = nil;
NSArray *searchAlbumsResults = nil;
NSArray *searchSongsResult=nil;


NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription

                                          entityForName:@"RunningSession" inManagedObjectContext:moc];




NSFetchRequest *requestData = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[requestData setEntity:entityDescription];
 [requestData setFetchLimit:1] ;


NSError *error;
// if get a entity, that means exists, so fetch it.


searchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestData error:&error];



for ( RunningSession *session in searchResults) {
    // Update the Records
    self.runnningSessionId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",session.runningSessionID];
    self.title=session.title;
    self.desc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",session.desc];


    [fetchRequest1 setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Albums"
                                         inManagedObjectContext:session.managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest1 setEntity:entityDescription];
    [fetchRequest1 setFetchLimit:1] ;

    searchAlbumsResults = [session.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 error:&error];




    NSMutableArray *tagNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //NSLog(@"Local Discount Shops:%@",discounts.shops);
    NSSet *tagA = session.albums;
    if (tagA.count>0) {





        for (Albums *tag in tagA
             ) {
            // NSLog(@"tag:%@",tag);
            NSString *albumID;
            NSString *aTitle;
            NSString *aPrice;
            NSString *aDuration;
            NSString *aUrl;
            NSString *aPurchasedHtml;
            NSString *aNonPurchasedHtml;



            if (tag.albumID != NULL) {
                albumID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tag.albumID]; //tag.shopId;
            }else{
                albumID = @"";
            }
            if (tag.title != NULL) {
                aTitle = tag.title;
            }
            else{
                aTitle = @"";
            }
            if (tag.price != NULL) {
                aPrice = tag.price;
            }
            else{
                aPrice = @"";
            }


            if (tag.duration != NULL) {
                aDuration = tag.duration;
            }
            else{
                aDuration = @"";
            }
            if (tag.url != NULL) {
                aUrl = tag.url;
            }
            else{
                aUrl = @"";
            }
            if (tag.purchasedHtml != NULL) {
                aPurchasedHtml = tag.purchasedHtml;
            }
            else{
                aPurchasedHtml = @"";
            }
            if (tag.nonPurchasedHtml != NULL) {
                aNonPurchasedHtml = tag.nonPurchasedHtml;
            }
            else{
                aNonPurchasedHtml = @"";
            }

            NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:albumID,@"Id",aTitle,@"Title",aPrice,@"Price", aDuration,@"Duration",
                                  albumUrl,@"Url",aPurchasedHtml,@"PurchasedItemsHtml",aNonPurchasedHtml,@"NonPurchasedItemsHtml", nil];

            [tagNamesArray addObject:dict];




            NSLog(@"tag.shop:%@",tag.songs);




            [fetchRequest2 setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Songs"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:tag.managedObjectContext]];
            [fetchRequest2 setEntity:entityDescription];
            [fetchRequest2 setFetchLimit:1];
            searchSongsResult = [tag.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:&error];




            NSMutableArray *songsNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            //NSLog(@"Local Discount Shops:%@",discounts.shops);
            NSSet *tags = tag.songs;


            if (tags.count>0) {

            for (Songs *tag in tags) {
                // NSLog(@"tag:%@",tag);
                NSString *sID;
                NSString *sTitle;
                NSString *startTime;


                if (tag.songsId !=NULL) {
                    sID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tag.songsId]; //tag.shopId;
                }else{
                    sID = @"";
                }
                if (tag.title != NULL) {
                    sTitle = tag.title;
                }
                else{
                    sTitle = @"";
                }
                if (tag.startTime != NULL) {
                    startTime = tag.startTime;
                }
                else{
                    startTime = @"";
                }


                NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:sID,@"Id",sTitle,@"Title",startTime,@"Duration", nil];

                [songsNamesArray addObject:dict];

            }





            }



            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:albumID,@"Id",albumTitle,@"Title",albumPrice,@"Price",albumDuration,@"Duration",albumUrl,@"Url",albumPurchasedHtml,@"PurchasedItemsHtml",albumNonPurchasedHtml,@"NonPurchasedItemsHtml",songsNamesArray,@"Songs", nil];
        }


    }
    //   NSPredicate *bobPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = 'Bob'"];
    //     NSLog(@"Bobs: %@", [discounts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bobPredicate]);

    NSMutableArray *albumArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    albumArray = [tagNamesArray mutableCopy];


    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.runnningSessionId,@"Id",title,@"Title",self.title,@"title",self.desc,@"Description",albumArray,@"Albums", nil];


    [self.runningSessionArray addObject:dict];
    //        [self StudentDiscountData];
    //  NSLog(@"studentDataArray:%@",self.studentDataArray);


}

NSLog(@"RunningSession: %@",self.runningSessionArray);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to all those steps getting session data is enough and from that you can get Albums list as you set the one to many relationship. And from each Album you will get Songs

```
AppDelegate *delegates = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = [delegates managedObjectContext];

if (runningSessionArray.count > 0) {
    [runningSessionArray removeAllObjects];
}

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSArray *searchResults = nil;
NSArray *searchAlbumsResults = nil;// not required
NSArray *searchSongsResult=nil;//not required


NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];//not required
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];//not required

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription

                                      entityForName:@"RunningSession" inManagedObjectContext:moc];




 NSFetchRequest *requestData = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 [requestData setEntity:entityDescription];
 [requestData setFetchLimit:1] ;


 NSError *error;
 // if get a entity, that means exists, so fetch it.


 searchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestData error:&error];
 //This returns array of sessions

 for ( RunningSession *session in searchResults) {

   NSArray *albumsArray = session.albums; //This returns Albums list as you set one to many relation
  for ( Album *album in albumsArray) {
    NSArray *songsArray = album.songs; //This returns songs list as you set one to many relation
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I am getting list of songs and albums now but I have one problem in parsing them in dictionary format, Like I am able to get number of songs and album but unable to get there title's Id's etc

Comment: Mean I want to save exact in same format in which I get from JSON to myarray and Dic, so I am able to get one single array having dictionary one every index like JSON.

Comment: Because when we adding this line 
NSArray *albumsArray = session.albums;
we get warning because session.album is NSSET and albumArray is an array.

Comment: When I am inserting Data in core data like this 
[album addSongsObject:song];
and when I retrieve data from DB it return an empty array of songs
and want to log album I got this information please have alook specially at songs
    songs =     (
        "0x10c0140c0 <x-coredata:///Songs/tE96EFE65-40CB-4D9E-97B5-186F974F892E8>",
        "0x10b47fb00 <x-coredata:///Songs/tE96EFE65-40CB-4D9E-97B5-186F974F892E7>",
        "0x10b5c5950 <x-coredata:///Songs/tE96EFE65-40CB-4D9E-97B5-186F974F892E6>"

Comment: NSArray *albumsArray = [session.albums allObjects]; // returns array

Comment: Please check this link, I have uploaded my insertion code here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072727/core-data-insertion

Comment: Did you get any error while inserting or while saving.. ?

Comment: Not any error but it gives warning of fatal error. But no exception or such a thing?